# wxScrolledWindow add and remove elements

Tags: c++, scrollbar, wxwidgets, dynamically-generated

I have a wxScrolledWindow object filled with elements (pictures) (every element add with the class ThumbNail which uses dc.paint). I would like to dynamically change the elements with new once (not the same number) (change of folder by the user).

How can I empty all the items in wxScrolledWindow object and put new once back in? And then reset the scrollbars.

```
    _ScrolThumbs = new wxScrolledWindow(_pMainPanel);

        wxGridSizer *m_swSizer = new wxGridSizer(1,1,0);
        _ScrolThumbs->SetSizer(m_swSizer);  // Sets the window to have the given layout sizer.
std::vector<ThumbNail*> _Thumbs;
        for(int i=0;i < FilePr::Instance()->GetNumThumbs() ;i++)
        {
            _Thumbs.push_back(new ThumbNail(_ScrolThumbs, PicName[i]));
            _ScrolThumbs ->GetSizer()->Add (_Thumbs[i], 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
        }
```

Then I tried to do this (when a button is hit):

```
    wxWindowList& lst = _ScrolThumbs->GetChildren();
    //if (!lst.empty())
    std::cout << lst.size() << '\n';
    while(!lst.empty()) //for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) //lst.size()
    {
        wxWindow *wnd = lst.back();
        wnd->Destroy();
    }
```

But putting new elements back in, like I did above does not work...

Any idea how to do this or were to find help on the web? Thanks!

Comment: `lst.back()` will not remove the last element from the list; you need to also do a `pop_back()`. The `while` loop will be an infinite loop as far as I can tell (or will make a mess calling `Destroy` on the same pointer repeatedly). Instead, you should remove the children from the sizer: just do `_ScrolThumbs ->GetSizer()->Clear(true);`. After adding the new children, do a `_ScrolThumbs->Layout();`. I don't know how much this will help, since you didn't give enough information about what "does not work" means. I can put these in an answer if it helps.

Comment: Off topic: using identifiers that start with an underscore and a capital letter is illegal in C++ in user code - those are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks a LOT!! this does the trick:). I will checkout the '_'. I picked it up at the wrong sit eI guess. (Sorry I can not give you the right answer award). Are there rules about good practise in writing code?

Comment: There's no shortage of rules, that's for sure :-). I guess you could start with the FAQs and other links at [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org) (if you haven't already) and go from there. (You probably picked up the underscore style while reading standard library code; that code is allowed to use that combination, since it's part of "the implementation". It does it on purpose, ugly as it looks, precisely because other code can't; it's intended to avoid clashes with user code macros and other oddities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_ScrolThumbs->GetSizer()->Clear(true);
// or
_ScrolThumbs->DestroyChildren();
```